# Reading a file uploade in my module without saving it

Tags: 7, files

I'm creating an module and there I want to read a text file.

**I don't want to save the file.**

In my my_module.module file I have

```
function my_module_upload_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['upload'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
    );

    $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Upload'),
    );

    return $form;
}
function my_module_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['upload']);
    $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
}
```

I get the error "Trying to get property of non-object" at

```
$url = file_create_url($file->uri);
```

Can someone point me how to read the file correctly (without saving it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself!

```
function my_module_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    //saved the file into a tmp folder (location to save not set)
    //this will also add a pointer in the database
    $file = file_save_upload('upload', array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('txt'),
    ));

    //get the content in the file
    $content = file_get_contents($file->uri);

    //remove the file in temp and the pointer in the database
    file_delete($file);
}
```

Comment: Best Answer, Was looking for this. Mine wasn't working because I was saving into my `::public` directory.

Comment: This works in Drupal 8 as well but it is not the recommended way to delete files. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_delete/8.2.x